# Facebook NativeAdsManager getting out of memory exception in RecyclerView

Tags: android, facebook, android-recyclerview, native-ads

I'm creating an application that is using [`NativeAdsManager`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/nativeadsmanager) within a `RecyclerView`. When I load the ads, I'm getting an out of memory exception. This is where I initialise the `NativeAdsManager`:

```
NativeAdsManager manager = new NativeAdsManager(MainActivity.this,PLACEMENT_ID,5);
manager.setListener(MainActivity.this); 
manager.loadAds(NativeAd.MediaCacheFlag.ALL);
```

This is my log when I get the error:

```
07-07 16:44:37.513 14833-15332/com.example.fbads E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 1324560-byte allocation.
07-07 16:44:37.528 14833-15332/com.example.fbads E/k: Error downloading image: https://external.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAUgFkrAP5pYhO4&w=796&h=416&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fads%2Fimage%2F%3Fd%3DAQJm1ZveY2ilC4oqvu3Hf63USTwVITC5XBV-qrlWjCWeNgKXrAn5SBB9J6cFyDL0sqpnMWqMDehXuXprwbAKycgE-kskX1q8_jpYlyB4sfhCxSRpHM_5n9ZA8-xhlcZ-VxlRs9DT4i5qeLy6kEZxOSQG&cfs=1&ext=jpg
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:620)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:376)
 at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:402)
 at com.facebook.ads.internal.util.m.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.facebook.ads.internal.util.k.b(Unknown Source)
 at com.facebook.ads.internal.util.k.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Any reasons why this is happening? Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: The file you're trying to decode is 45kb. There's a very slim chance it would cause an OOM unless you are really unlucky. Do a heap dump and trace memory allocations. It's the best way to deal with OOM. Here's a good strarting guide in case you need it. Good luck. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html  (This could be a facebook SDK problem which I'm not aware of too)

Comment: Please post the full error log and show us the exact line where the exception occurs